# Adding plot into presentation without saving it as an image

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to add an image into a powerpoint presentation. I am able to achieve it but I want to add it without saving it into the explorer.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index = range(1, 7), columns = list('ABCD'))

# creating and saving the plot in the explorer
plot_1 = plt.plot(df)
plt.savefig('plot_1.png')
plot_1 = 'plot_1.png'

presentation = Presentation()
presentation.slide_width = Inches(16)
presentation.slide_height = Inches(9)
layout = presentation.slide_layouts[6]
slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(layout)
left = Inches(1)
top = Inches(0.5)
plot = slide.shapes.add_picture(plot_1, left, top)
presentation.save('test.pptx')
```

Any idea how to add plot into the presentation without saving them into the explorer?

Comment: Use an "in-memory" file like `io.BytesIO`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "add_chart" function provided by python-pptx. It will create create interactive charts just like you create from Powerpoint. [Official documentation link](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/charts.html)

```
chart_data = ChartData()
chart_data.categories = 'Foo', 'Bar'
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (1.2, 2.3))
chart_data.add_series('Series 2', (3.4, 4.5))

x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4)
graphic_frame = shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
)
chart = graphicFrame.chart
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check and let you know :)